# How do I check the Captcha?

Tags: support, questions

I'm sorry, but I'm a little bad at English.
I want to ask a question on Puzzling SE,
but they always asks me to check the Captcha.

How do I check the Captcha?

There's nowhere to input the Captcha code.

EDIT: I didn't find the "I'm not a robot" box.

Answer (score 2):

Which step are you having issues with?

[By default](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/captcha), you should just see a reCAPTCHA checkbox with "I'm not a robot" written next to it. Just click/tap the empty square on the left, which will add a checkmark and let you in.

[image: I'm not a robot]

If the automated captcha can't verify you as not being a bot (can happen depending on what device/browser/extensions you're using), you'll get [an additional verification step](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/?hl=en) that may require you to identify images of signs/buses/cars/etc. Follow the instructions, select all the appropriate images (they sometimes refresh and you have to continue selecting new images), and click Verify once done.

[image: buses]

<sub>In this one, I had to click the four bus images, then the "SKIP" button changed to "NEXT". I clicked that and had to find traffic lights in another grid of images. After that the "NEXT" button became "VERIFY" and I was let through.</sub>

Comment: I didn't find the "I'm not a robot" box.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat - well that's pretty odd... Do you have any ad/script/tracking blockers enabled? The captcha is loaded from google, so it could trip a plug-in that doesn't like scripts being loaded from different domains to the page itself...

Comment: Sorry, it's because I can't access Google. But now I can ask a question successfully.

Comment: It happened again!!!!!!

Comment: @Scratch---Cat - that's frustrating :\ One pattern I've noticed is that you get a captcha is you've stayed in the page for a long time. Maybe try composing your post in notepad and copy/pasting it into a freshly loaded page? You could also try raising the question (or searching for similar ones) on the main SE network meta...

Comment: It happens occasionally.